# Compile `.jsp` file directly to plain text as part of an ant task

Tags: java, jsp, ant, template-engine, build.xml

Is there a way to compile a `.jsp` file to a text file as part of an ant task?

I understand that typically a `.jsp` file will have certain variables that won't be known until an HTTP request is made. But, in my case, my `.jsp` can be generated completely from the variables declared in the file.

I also understand that `.jsp` files are typically compiled to Java source code, but I would like to compile my `.jsp` files directly to plain text.

Answer (score 1):

First from JSPs a Java file is created. Then is is compiled to a .class file. This can be done when JSP is called or it can also be precompiled. In both cases you get a servlet that produces the content according to the logic defined in JSP.

You cannot execute the code defined in JSP before it is deployed to a web container.

Even if your JSP contains plain text only or HTML only, still a source code for a Java servlet will be generated, then this source will be compiled to a class file, then this servlet will be executed and will produce the content that you originally had in JSP. I don't see any sense to use JSP in such case.

If you have template that you can render to a text **without** deploying it to a web container, then why are you trying to do that via JSPs? I'd suggest you to consider template engines like Velocity or Thymeleaf (Thymeleaf has also offline renderers). Then I would suggest that you rename your generated content accordingly, e.g. to .txt, .html, .css, etc.

Comment: Currently my implementation is in Velocity, but I was hoping to move to JSP since my team is already familiar with that. How is Velocity different from JSP? From your answer, it sounds like JSP requires a web container, whereas Velocity does not. Is that right? In that case, what is a web container and why does JSP need one?

Comment: Velocity is pretty limited. Where as with JSP you get the full power of Java. In a simple case if you render 2-3 properties, there is no much difference, but still with velocity you have more overhead (e.g. load template explicitly). With JSP you can embed pure Java code into JSP (bad practice, actually, but nevertheless powerful). In JSP you can implement complex rendering logic with so called custom tags. You embed such custom tag and your JSP will implicitly invoke the logic (in Java) behind this tag. And the code of JSP remains compact and good readable. I'd suggest you use JSP as JSP :)

Comment: But without knowing exactly your requirements and constraints it is hard to say it JSPs are the best solution. May be Thymeleaf could be better, or Angular, React or Vue could be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks @mentallurg!

Answer (score 0):

I think [Arco](http://arco.samajackun.com/arco-maven-plugin/faq.html) would suit for your needs.

Comment: This looks close, but I need to compile my `.jsp`s directly to text rather than Java source code.

Comment: @johnnyodonnell Of corse. But _when_ will you compile your JSP to text? I suppose in **execution time**, isn't it? Arco will transform your JSP to a Java class that will produce your desired text output.

Comment: I'm looking to compile to text during compile time.